# Auto update chat system

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops

I am trying to auto update my chat system whenever a user
Types a message but there are no good tutorials on YouTube i can update when a user starts typing but i want it to be live ive tried:
 Infinite loops (page crashed) and
 When a user Types update (i want it live)

And my page crashed. 
I have access to jquery ajax and built in JavaScript ajax.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to work with **long polling** or **comet** or **web socket** features for auto-updating your chat system, while you want to check the user, starts typing or no.

Comment: I have a question comet and long polling technology is now being used frequently or not ?

Comment: Yes, as I know that technologies like the comet are very used.